# EnableIdpInitiatedSignon page property not available in ADFS Server 3.0

Tags: active-directory, adfs, windows-server-2012-r2, ws-federation, adfs3.0

I have a Windows Server 2012 R2 datacenter machine with that I created the Active Directory Federation Server Environment. After completing the installation and configuration, I tried enabling the IdpInitiatedsignon property but the property isn't available in the properties list. I have checked with some sites and they suggested updating OS and I have tried that but the same problem repeats. If there are any ways to solve this issue kindly suggest them.

I have attached the picture of the properties list that I got with 'Get-AdfsProperties' where EnableIdpInitiatedSignon isn't available.

[image: Properties list of ADFS where IdpInitiatedsignon was unavailable]

Comment: StackOverflow is for programming questions only -- and this doesn't seem to be to be one. Probably better place to ask this is https://ServerFault.com

Answer (score 1):

It's only available in ADFS 2016 and later.

This page is available by [default](https://blog.rmilne.ca/2017/06/20/how-to-enable-idpinitiatedsignon-page-in-ad-fs-2016/) in the AD FS 2012 R2 and earlier versions.

Comment: I have tried but page https://<fed-service-name>/adfs/ls/idpinitiatedsignon.aspx (or htm) is not available.